# Html form submission

Tags: html, forms

I have the HTML code given below. When I try to submit the inner form within the div element I found that the form submitted twice.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<bodY>
<form method="post" action="test.do">
<input type="text" name="test">
<div id="testdiv">
<form method="post" action="test.do">
</form>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

I tested the above with IE7, and I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nesting forms is ill advised as it will cause unexpected results such as you are experiencing.  Remove the nested form, and only use one.  If you explain the purpose of the form better, we could probably help more in how to achieve the results you are after.

I haven't seen many cases where nesting forms was a legitimate solution to a problem, so I would suggest rethinking the problem.

Comment: your right,here my scenario is different .Purpose of nested form is,i dont want to submit all the form fields.

Comment: @User, can you not filter the ones you need to use server side?  That would be the easiest solution.  Otherwise you could have multiple forms (not nested) and have a button that uses Javascript to select which forum to submit.

Comment: @ Tom Gullen:This way it is submitting whole the form.

Comment: @User, have multiple forms and use Javascript to 'pick' the correct form to submit.  Or refactor the design of your forms (IE break it up onto multiple pages).  I'm not sure what the context is here, so can't really help more than that.